# twitter/social data mining - Ruby or Django?

Tags: python, ruby-on-rails, ruby, django

I am a decent c/c++ programmer, but don't know much about web dev. I am interested in twitter/social data mining. So which is a better tool - RoR or Django? I am on level zero in both ruby and python. But python's syntax seemed easier to understand/learn. But the main Qs is that which tool has better mining related APIs?

Thanks!!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

They both have all what you need. But Python does better here I think. Python has a very interesting library for text mining called [NLTK](https://www.nltk.org/), and [Numpy/Scipy](https://numpy.org) for analytical computations which allow you to achieve almost c comparable performances. On the other hand for pure data mining I'd suggest python+[Pandas](https://pandas.pydata.org/) (Pandas is really well written and fast and there is no ruby equivalent as far as I know) or python + some R code called thru [rpy](https://rpy.sourceforge.io/). If in your data mining code you need to compute some symbolic math you can decide to use [Sympy](https://www.sympy.org/) (slower because it's written in python but very complete) or [Theano](https://web.archive.org/web/20201108233358/http://www.deeplearning.net/software/theano/) (way faster but with less features; it can even make your code run on the GPU thru CUDA)

Comment: So i guess i will go with Python...Thank you!!

Comment: Glad to help. P.S. take also a look at pypy ;)

Comment: any good source to learn python :)

Answer (score 1):

If you are merely collecting data from twitter, you don't need a MVC frame work like Django or RoR. Actually you can use [C++ libraries](https://dev.twitter.com/docs/twitter-libraries#cplusplus) to collect data from Twitter, store them in database, build the indexing and so on, and then use C or C++ to perform data mining task against your data. Or you can performance the analysis on the go.

If you want to build your own web interface to present your work, or the likes, Django and RoR are both very good and easy to pick up framework.

Comment: Thanks, yes my main aim is to have a web interface

Answer (score 0):

This is not a real question, please read the [faq](https://stackoverflow.com/faq)

Comment: Thanks but where should i ask then?

Comment: You need to make your own research about any framework or make a specific question about this issue

Comment: I agree but post this in the comments of the question, not as an answer.